# hex() method giving error when used with custom object

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, magic-methods

I am trying to emulate the built-in `hex()` method for custom object using magic method `__hex__`.I am getting the following error which I'm not able to figure out why its doing so.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x= x

    def __hex__(self):
        return hex(self.x)

p1=Point(10)
print(hex(p1))

TypeError: 'point' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

but when i call `hex` method using `p1.__hex__()` instead of `hex(p1)`, the code works fine

```
>>>print(p1.__hex__())
0xa
```

can you explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make an `__index__` method:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __index__(self):
        return self.x
```